# ${2:-$2} what does this piece of code do

Tags: bash

I forgot a little piece of code in my program, and yes it is really stupid: 
Here is a code snippet.

```
checkInputNum(){
    if [[ $1 = *[^0-9]* ]]; then
        echo "Error: '$1' is not valid Value." >&2
        echo "Enter a value in numbers" >&2
        read input
        checkInputNum ${input}
    elif [ -z "$1" ]; then
        ${2:-$2}
        input=$2
        checkinputNum $input
    else
        input=$1
        echo ${input}
    fi
}
```

Comment: [{parameter:-word}](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html): If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

Comment: as usual, you'll understand what is happening (with a little thought), by turning on the shell debugging/trace feature; add `set -vx` as the first line of your function. When the code is executed, you'll see each line before it is executed and an 2nd copy preceeded with `+` that shows the variables expanded to their values. AND of course, as people have commented, `${parameter:-word}` is of interest here. Good luck.

Comment: What do you mean that you "forgot" this code? You wrote it but you forgot why you wrote it this way?

Comment: Barmar - you can say i forgot my code. That is Way comments are so important. By with jaypal comment and Poulsen answars i know why and what the elif does. It is supposed to be used together with a using a ramdom or a default value. If the user hits 'enter' to use a default value that is passed as arg nr.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a no-op that leads to infinite recursion.  That line is hit iff:

```
[ -z "$1" ]
```

is true.  This is true only when the string `"$1"` is zero length, i.e. when there is no first parameter.  So there's also no second parameter.  Now:

```
${2:-$2}
```

evaluates to `$2` if `$2` isn't set!  So it defaults to a zero length string.  This empty string is then "executed".  Which is a no-op.  You then recursively call your self with this "no argument".  You're then in exactly the same situation that got you there in the first place.  You're in an infinite loop.

Comment: You could get there with `checkInputNum '' param`. An empty first parameter, non-empty second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it does anything. From the `bash` documentation:

> **${parameter:-word}**
>           Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

In your code, if the variable is unset or null, its own value is substituted, and that value is empty. As far as I can tell, that line is equivalent to just:

```
$2
```

When there's a second argument to the function, and it's not empty, it will be executed as a command.